# вывод наиболее частого значения во вложенных в списки словарях python

Tags: python, list, словари

Есть список учеников в нескольких классах, нужно вывести самое частое имя в каждом классе

```
school_students = [
[ # это – первый класс
{'first_name': 'Вася'},
{'first_name': 'Вася'},
                     ],
[ # это – второй класс
{'first_name': 'Маша'},
{'first_name': 'Маша'},
{'first_name': 'Оля'},
]
]
```

Пример вывода:
Самое частое имя в классе 1: Вася
Самое частое имя в классе 2: Маша

Comment: Вы явно как-то не так данные храните, уже второй вопрос словари содержат один и тот же ключ и хранят 1 пару всего

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути этот вопрос не особо отличается от вашего предыдущего. Так как вы храните список списков то соответственно поверх всего модно добавить `for`. Было бы еще хорошо если в бы словаре был ключ который указывает какому классу принадлежат имена. Тогда не нежно добавлять переменную `cl` либо считать кол-во итераций

```
from collections import Counter

cl = 1
for item in school_students:
    temp = [i['first_name'] for i in item]
    c = Counter(temp)
    print(f'Самое частое имя в классе {cl}: {c.most_common()[0][0]}')
    cl += 1
```

Comment: вывод: Самое частое имя в классе Counter({'Вася': 2}): Вася
Самое частое имя в классе Counter({'Маша': 2, 'Оля': 1}): Маша

Comment: @СергейСергеев поправил